# Order of Select2 selection based on array of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to set the order of selected items in `Select2` based on an array.

A simple solution has already been proposed to append items in the order with which they are clicked in the dropdown menu (see 2rba's answer on 2017-10-26 in this [discussion](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106)):

```
        $("#selectCriteria").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
          var element = evt.params.data.element;
          var $element = $(element);
          $element.detach();
          $(this).append($element);
          $(this).trigger("change");
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is mimick this behavior, but when passing an array of the selected items instead of manually clicking them in the list. I tried the following command:

```
displayed_items = ["b", "c", "a"];  
$('#selectCriteria').val(displayed_items).trigger('change');
```

But the order isn't preserved. I tried looping the command with one element at a time, but each new call overwrites the previous element:

```
 $('#selectCriteria').val("b").trigger('change'); 
 $('#selectCriteria').val("c").trigger('change'); 
 $('#selectCriteria').val("a").trigger('change');
```

I see two possible solutions to this, but lack the background to make them work:

1. How should the iteration above be adapted to *not* overwrite the previously added
   value?
2. How could I incorporate the approach shown in this
   [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/bkc7qt36/12/) (from vol7ron's [posts on github](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106)) which does pretty
   much what I'm asking (i.e. toggling on/off the
   `.data('preserved-order',selected)`)? As it is using `JSX` I'm
   not sure how I could reuse that script in my plain JS/jQuery script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here you go

**EDIT:**

this is not the prettiest solution, but it gets the job done.

you would have to call `initSelect` function that takes an array of `value`s as a parameter. i left some comments in the code.

```js
displayed_items = $('#selected_items').val().split(',');
    
function selectItem(target, id) { // refactored this a bit, don't pay attention to this being a function
  var option = $(target).children('[value='+id+']');
  option.detach();
  $(target).append(option).change();
} 

function customPreSelect() {
  let items = $('#selected_items').val().split(',');
  $("select").val('').change();
  initSelect(items);
}

function initSelect(items) { // pre-select items
  items.forEach(item => { // iterate through array of items that need to be pre-selected
    let value = $('select option[value='+item+']').text(); // get items inner text
    $('select option[value='+item+']').remove(); // remove current item from DOM
    $('select').append(new Option(value, item, true, true)); // append it, making it selected by default
  });
}

$('select').select2();
$('select').on('select2:select', function(e){
  selectItem(e.target, e.params.data.id);
});

initSelect(displayed_items); // call init
```

```css
select {
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.control-group {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <p>Provide comma separated items to be pre selected and click the button</p>
  <div class="control-group">
    <input id="selected_items" value="b,c,a"/>
    <button onclick="customPreSelect()">Init</button>
  </div>

  <select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b" >B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, however this seems more like a reimplementation of the first snippet in my question. Is your version supposed to also work when passing an array using e.g. the command `$('#select').val(myArray).trigger('change');`? That is what I'm trying to achieve. Could you kindly illustrate in your example how you would achieve this using a predetermined array e.g. `["b","a","d"]`?

Comment: Aha. Sorry, I misread. Give me a minute here and I'll update the answer.

Comment: also added a little playground control to make it more illustrative of what is going on

Comment: Thanks so much! It gets the job perfectly done indeed. Nearly plug'n'play also, I just had to adapt a bit the `[value='+item+']')` into `[value="'+item+'"]')` because I had some more complex names with spaces. But otherwise flawless!

Comment: glad to help. sorry about missing quotes

Answer (score 0):

This preserves attributes of the select2 options (e.g. titles used for tooltips):

```
function initSelect(items) {
    items.forEach(item => {
        var option = $('#selectCriteria').children('[value="' + item + '"]');
        option[0].selected = true;
        option.detach();
        $('#selectCriteria').append(option).change();
    })
}
```